# OpenCL: Moving data from global to local memory issue

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

I have an issue with the following snippet of code:

```
    tgid = (pixelLoc[get_global_id(0)].x + 0) + (pixelLoc[get_global_id(0)].y + 0) * imWidth;
    plid = (blockSize + 0) + (blockSize + 0) * (blockSize * 2 + 1);

    prevCache[plid] = prevFrame[tgid];

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    printf("%i : %i\n", prevCache[plid], prevFrame[tgid]);
```

The code should copy a single pixel value of image data to local memory. pixelLoc contains coordinates for all pixel locations which I want to move to local memory.

The issue I am getting is that the if conditional statement should print the same 2 numbers e.g: 34 : 34. As it should have moved the same value from prevFrame to prevCache, however, it is different values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try to put the barrier with local memory fence:
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

Comment: `prevFrame[tgid];` could have been written between the first read and the second. The barrier does never work with global data.

Comment: There is no global synchronization in OpenCL (because some work groups run to completion before others are even started). For global synchronization use separate kernels.